# React Native error requiring json file and displaying corresponding value

Tags: json, import, require, react-native

I am trying to build a word dictionary that translates English words to German words. It utilize a json file which, I believe, contain keys with English words and its corresponding German words as values.

1. The tutorial do that by using the require statement but I would like to know how to the import statement instead. I was following a tutorial from [here](https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/creating-a-dictionary-app-using-react-native-for-android--cms-24969).
2. I would like to know why I got the following error message.

The error image is as follows:

[image: Error Image]

My source code is as follows:

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {
  AppRegistry,
  Image,
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  TextInput,
  View
} from 'react-native';

var english_german = require('./english_german.json');

class Dictionary extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      input: '',
      output: ''
    }
    
    showMeaning: () => {
      // Use the ternary operator to check if the word
      // exists in the dictionary.
      var meaning = this.state.input in english_german ?
                      english_german[this.state.input] :
                      "Not Found";
      // Update the state
      this.setState({
      output: meaning});
    }
  }
  
 render() {
  var layout = 
   <View style = { styles.parent }>
    <Text>
     Type something in English:
    </Text>
        /*
    <TextInput text = { this.state.input }
          onChangeText={(e) => this.setState({input: e})}
        />
        */
        <TextInput
          onChangeText={(e) => this.setState({input: e})}
          text = { this.state.input }
          onSubmitEditing = { this.showMeaning }
        />
    <Text style = { styles.germanLabel }>
     It's German equivalent is:
    </Text>
    <Text style = { styles.germanWord }>
          { this.state.output }
    </Text>
   </View>
  ;
  return layout;
 }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
 // For the container View
 parent: {
  padding: 16
 },
 // For the Text Label
 germanLabel: {
  marginTop: 20,
  fontWeight: 'bold'
 },
 // For the Text meaning
 germanWord: {
  marginTop: 15,
  fontSize: 30,
  fontStyle: 'italic'
 }
});

AppRegistry.registerComponent('Dictionary', () => Dictionary);
```

The above error have been solved but it isn't working as shown:

[image]

Comment: The error says what is wrong pretty clearly :D Have you read it fully?

Comment: @HenrikR Argh! So embarrassing! I've downloaded the english_german.json file into my project but with the same code there's no error but there isn't any output shown when i typed in the english words.

Comment: @HenrikR Or should I put my showMeaning function outside of the constructor block? I'm confused.

Comment: That is true that show meaning should NOT be inside of constructor.

Comment: @HenrikR Hi I've shifted my showMeaning out of the constructor and it seems to run. But I've encountered a runtime error [as shown in this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44363098/react-native-undefined-is-not-an-object-evaluating-this-state-input).