# React Native Undefined is not an Object (evaluating 'this.state.input')

Tags: json, import, require, react-native

I am trying to build a word dictionary that translates English words to German words by following [this tutorial](https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/creating-a-dictionary-app-using-react-native-for-android--cms-24969). It utilize a json file which, I believe, contain keys with English words and its corresponding German words as values.

1. The tutorial do that by using the require statement `var english_german = require('./english_german.json');` but I would like to know if there is an alternative by using the import statement instead.
2. The main problem I am facing, though, is that I am getting a "Undefined is not an Object (evaluating 'this.state.input')" error when I type in a word in the TextInput and hitting enter.

My source code is as follows:

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {
  AppRegistry,
  Image,
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  TextInput,
  View
} from 'react-native';

var english_german = require('./english_german.json');

class Dictionary extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      input: '',
      output: ''
    }
    

  }
  
  showMeaning() {
    // Use the ternary operator to check if the word
    // exists in the dictionary.
    var meaning = this.state.input in english_german ?
                    english_german[this.state.input] :
                    "Not Found";
    // Update the state
    this.setState({output: meaning});
  }
  
 render() {
  var layout = 
   <View style = { styles.parent }>
    <Text>
     Type something in English:
    </Text>
        <TextInput
          onChangeText={(e) => this.setState({input: e})}
          text = { this.state.input }
          onSubmitEditing = { this.showMeaning }
        />
    <Text style = { styles.germanLabel }>
     It's German equivalent is:
    </Text>
    <Text style = { styles.germanWord }>
          { this.state.output }
    </Text>
   </View>
  ;
  return layout;
 }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
 // For the container View
 parent: {
  padding: 16
 },
 // For the Text Label
 germanLabel: {
  marginTop: 20,
  fontWeight: 'bold'
 },
 // For the Text meaning
 germanWord: {
  marginTop: 15,
  fontSize: 30,
  fontStyle: 'italic'
 }
});

AppRegistry.registerComponent('Dictionary', () => Dictionary);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a binding problem, add this in your constructor:

```
this.showMeaning = this.showMeaning.bind(this);
```

This will ensure that `this` object in your `showMeaning` method refers to your `Dictionary` component. Alternatively, you could use arrow function in your `showMeaning` method like so:

```
showMeaning = () => { /* rest of code */ }
```

The arrow function preserves the context of `this`. So the use of `bind` isn't required.

Comment: You can also automatically bind by using arrow syntax: `showMeaning = () => { //Method here }`

Comment: @AndrewBreen Without the binding, what does 'this' refers to?

Comment: It depends, it could refer to other components, but to be sure it's better to console.log it.

Comment: @D-reaper How do i console.log it? Pardon my ignorance, it's my first time doing an android app.

Comment: put `console.log(this.state)` in your `showMeaning` method and look at the output in chrome console. The detailed explanation is available here: https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/debugging.html.

Answer (score 1):

This is because you are referring to `this` inside of `showMeaning`. Bind that function to right `this` inside `constructor` like this `this.showMeaning = this.showMeaning.bind(this)`.

I highly recommend you to read basics of React. For example here is documentation for your problem: https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/handling-events.html